# Encapsulating Threads creates problems

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have the following encapsulation for my `pthread_t` threads:

```
#include <pthread.h>

class Thread
{
public:
  void         run(const int);
  static void  *run_helper(void *);
  bool         startThread(int);
  void         joinThread();

  pthread_t     th;      
};
```

Where `run` is my thread routine, and `run_helper` is the following:

```
void     *Thread::run_helper(int num)
{
  return (Thread *)this->run(num);
}
```

I start my threads like such:

```
bool    Thread::startThread(intptr_t arg)
{
  return (pthread_create(&this->th, NULL, &run_helper(arg), (void *)(intptr_t)arg));
}
```

But when I compile, I get the following errors:

> error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
>      return (pthread_create(&this->th, NULL, &run_helper(arg), (void *)(intptr_t)arg));
>
> error: ‘this’ is unavailable for static member functions
>      return (Thread *)this->run(num);

And despite trying, I can't seem to make this encapsulation work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first error, you need to cast the third argument into `(void*(*)(void*))` and remove `&` (maybe the casting isn't neccessary).

```
pthread_create(&this->th, NULL, (void*(*)(void*))run_helper(arg), (void *)(intptr_t)arg);
```

The second error, you are trying to use pointer to `this` in a static function, but the function isn't called on any object, therefore you can't use `this` in a function like that. The solution is to cast `arg` into `Thread*` and then call the non-static `run` function.

Comment: The first error is out of the way. Could you please illustrate the second solution?

Comment: `((Thread*)arg)->run()`, but I don´t know about casting the argument into `intptr_t`, you can stick to `void*`

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue might specifically be `&this->th`. `&` has higher precedence than `->`. Perhaps try `&(this->th)`.